# Windrose legend bracket format and loc

Tags: python, matplotlib, windrose, rose-plot

Below I have plotted a wind rose using Windrose based on [this](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjuz72Gh9jPAhUmLMAKHWZxCuwQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpypi%2Fwindrose%2F&usg=AFQjCNGHVhwNYp_f2VtyGfBtsA61zp0duw). Firstly, the legend is covering part of the rose but when I try to use `loc` to set its location the legend disappears.

Secondly, the legend closing brackets are wrong i.e. `[0.0 : 1.0[` any idea how I fix this to `[0.0 : 1.0]`

[image: legend open bracket in place of close]

code:

```
from windrose import WindroseAxes
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("C:\2007_GG_wind rose.csv")
ws_SAR = df[' SARwind_10m']
wd_SAR = df['wind direction SAR model_int']
ws_mde = df['gg_mde']
wd_mde = df['wind direction MDE ']

ax=WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(wd_SAR,ws_SAR,normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
ax.set_legend()
plt.title("SAR 10m U",y=1.08) #y=1.08 raises the title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the original windrose.py from your python folder to your desired working directory. Name the copy somehow else, e.g. windrose_edit.py. Edit the file and look for the get_labels() function. I edited like this, but you can adopt it to your purpose.

```
def get_labels():
        labels = np.copy(self._info['bins'])
        labels = ["%.1f : %0.1f" %(labels[i], labels[i+1]-0.1) \
                  for i in range(len(labels)-1)]
        return labels
```

also you can increase the fontsize of the legend some lines below.

```
def set_legend(self):
    l = self.legend(borderaxespad=-0.10)
    plt.setp(l.get_texts(), fontsize=12)
```

Finally import your edited file for example
import windrose_edit as wind2

and use it with

```
winddir_ = yourdata
windspeed_ = yourdata

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8), dpi=100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w')
rect = [0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8]

ax = wind2.WindroseAxes(fig, rect, facecolor='w')

ax.contourf(winddir_, windspeed_, bins=6, normed=True, cmap=cm.RdYlBu_r)
ax.set_legend()
```

it's not beautiful although a relatively fast and lazy workaround