# Python Windrose Legend Labels

Tags: python, label, legend, rose-plot

I am trying to take full control of the legend in the Windrose; the legend is controlled by the bins, which can be called using the `ax.info['bins']`. However, I want to change the name of the bin groups.

[image: Bin group names]

Looking online, the only solution I found was to edit the .py file of the windrose, edit it and then reimport it into the python script.

[Python Windrose legend bracket format and loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024824/python-windrose-legend-bracket-format-and-loc)

I was looking for an easier method, as I plan to have different bins for various plots within the script. So far i have tried `label` and `set_label` which does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

By adding a labels argument in ax.set_legend and changing the script to accept the argument. I also added a small validation that displays error in case the labels do not match the handles.

`ax.set_legend(labels = ['T', 'S', 'M'], title="Failure Mode", loc="upper left")`

```
    def get_labels(labels, decimal_places=1):
        _decimal_places = str(decimal_places)

        fmt = (
            "[%." + _decimal_places + "f " +
            ": %0." + _decimal_places + "f"
        )

        if labels is None:
            labels = np.copy(self._info['bins'])
            if locale.getlocale()[0] in ['fr_FR']:
                fmt += '['
            else:
                fmt += ')'
            labels = [fmt % (labels[i], labels[i + 1])
                for i in range(len(labels) - 1)]
        else:
            if len(labels) != len(self._info['bins']) -1 :
                print("ERROR")
            labels = labels

        return labels


    kwargs.pop('handles', None)

    decimal_places = kwargs.pop('decimal_places', 1)
    labels = kwargs.pop('labels', None)

    handles = get_handles()
    labels = get_labels(labels, decimal_places)
    self.legend_ = mpl.legend.Legend(self, handles, labels, loc, **kwargs)
    return self.legend_
```

more info: [Github issue solution](https://github.com/python-windrose/windrose/issues/103)

Answer (score 0):

If set_label not working, try this:

```
wind_bins = [0, 2, 4]
wind_labels = ["a", "b", "c"]
ax.contourf(x, y,bins=wind_bins, cmap=cm.viridis_r)
#set bbox_anchor before modif
legend = ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
#get legend text
legend_texts = legend.get_texts()
#change legend text
for j,lab in enumerate(wind_labels):
    legend_texts[j].set_text(lab)
```